# Issue Passing MySQL2 results back to file calling the function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, mysql2

I'm trying to write a Node.JS + MySQL application, and I'm running in to an Async issue. Although I can console log the result right before returning it, it displays as "undefined" on the front side (index.js). What am I doing wrong here, and how can I change this?

**connections.js**

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const db = mysql.createConnection(
    {
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'Password1',
        database: 'employee'
    },
);

module.exports = db;
```

**index.js**

```js
const inquirer = require('inquirer');
const db = require('./db/connections');
const cTable = require('console.table');
const { getDepartments, addDepartment } = require('./utils/departmentFunctions');

let endProgram = false;

const mainMenuQuestions = [
    {
        type: 'list',
        name: 'next',
        message: '? What would you like to do?',
        choices: ['View All Employees', 'Add Employee', 'Update Employee Role', 'View All Roles', 'Add Role', 'View All Departments', 'Add Department', 'Quit', ]
    }
  ];

const promptUser = () => {
    return inquirer.prompt(mainMenuQuestions);
}

async function startApp() {
    let isFinished = false;
    
    while(!isFinished) {
        let next = await promptUser();
        if(next.next === 'View All Departments') {
            console.log(``);
            await console.log(getDepartments());
            console.log(``);
        } else if(next.next === 'Add Department') {
            addDepartment();
        } else if(next.next === 'View All Employees') {

        }else if(next.next === 'Add Employee') {

        } else if(next.next === 'Update Employee Role') {

        } else if(next.next === 'View All Roles') {

        } else if(next.next === 'Add Role') {

        } else {
            isFinished = true;
        }
    }
}

startApp();
```

**departmentFunctions.js**

```js
const db = require('../db/connections');
const inquirer = require('inquirer');
const cTable = require('console.table');

getDepartments = () => {
    db.query(`SELECT * FROM departments`, function(err, results, fields) {
        console.log(results);
        return results;
    });
};

module.exports = {
  getDepartments
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `index.js` you have this:

```
await console.log(getDepartments());
```

But this `console.log` is destroying the intended effect of `await`:

- `console.log` is executed synchronously (it doesn't wait for the `getDepartments()` promise to resolve), and outputs a pending promise object.
- `console.log` itself returns `undefined`, and `await` will interpret that is a resolved promise with `undefined` as fulfillment value. As a consequence, the execution will be restored in the next tick and resume while the promise you really wanted to wait for is still pending.

To correct this, put the `console.log` in the asynchronous part of the code (i.e. *after* `getDepartments()` resolved):

```
const departments = await getDepartments();
console.log(departments);
```